# Click event not firing when attached in directive compile

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to attach click event for li's from inside of compile function and I can see the ng-click being present in the dom but the event is not fired.

```
compile:function (elem, attrs){

      //elem.find('li').attr('data-ng-click', 'hello()');
      elem.find('li').attr('ng-click', "hello($event)");

      return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.hello = function ($event) {
            console.log($event);
            alert('click triggered')
          };       
 }
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/o8JyJM?p=preview

Comment: Can you explain more generally what you're trying to accomplish I took a gander at the plunkr you posted and am having trouble understanding the goal overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding an attribute that is itself a directive won't cause it to be processed.  Every element that is going to have directives in it needs to be run through `$compile` for the link function to be created and then the link function needs to be called with a scope object passed to it (typically created using `$rootScope.new()`).  All that said there are typically easier ways to accomplish what you want just using the `ng-click` in the template (which is compiled) or using `element.bind("click",function(evt){})`.   I'll fix up the plunkr in a bit here too.

Answer (score 0):

The **scope is not available in the compile stage of the directive.** it is available only at the link phase. i suggest you to switch the compile to a link function (if you dont have some specific need for compile function like in the snippet above.)